# Dart: function's parameter notation

Tags: function, parameters, dart, notation

I sometimes find stuff like this:

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
final response = await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}
```

where the parsePhotos function is:

```
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

I can't understand the `compute(parsePhotos, response.body)`: the `parePhotos` function takes in the responseBody parameter, but, as the `compute` is written, it seems that doesn't receive it. So, can someone explain me this notation, please? 
P.s. Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
```

`parsePhotos` and `response.body` are just two independent parameters.
The first is a reference to the `parsePhotos` function passed to the `compute`s `callback` parameter, and the second is is the response data from `client.get(...)` that is passed to the `message` parameter of the `compute` function.

What `compute` does is to create a new isolate with `parsePhotos` as entry point (like `main()` for the main isolate) and then passes `message` to it as parameter.

So it is *not* this line `return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);` that passes `response.body` to `parsePhotos` but

```
final Isolate isolate = await Isolate.spawn(
    _spawn,
    new _IsolateConfiguration<Q, R>(
      callback,
      message,
```

from the `compute` implementation https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!